# TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' opencv python

Tags: image, python-2.7, opencv

I tried to crop an image using opencv following this code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import csv
path_image= '/home/'
img=cv2.imread(path_image+"image1.png")
img1=img[40:102,2442:2448]
```

but l got an error executing :

```
 img1=img[40:102,2442:2448]

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: @DeepSpace It has to be `'/home/image1.png'`... I guess

Comment: See the docs for `imread`. It explains when and why `imread` might return `None`:http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#Mat%20imread(const%20string&%20filename,%20int%20flags). Either the file your are trying to open is not found or it is in an unsupported format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
img=cv2.imread(os.path.join(path_image,'image1.png'))
```